# Using Regex, how to check if second to last character is odd

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to wrap my head around Regex, but having some troubles with the basics.

I want to check to see if a the last character in a string is either a "0" or a "5", but I also want to check to is if the second to last character (if it exists) is odd.

If it matters, I'm trying to do this in Javascript for some form validation. I have the following Regex to satisfy my first condition of checking the last character and making sure its a "0" or a "5"

```
/([0|5]$)/g
```

But how do I properly add a 2nd condition to see if the 2nd to last character exists and is odd? Something like the following...?

```
/([0|5]$)([1|3|5|7|9]$-1)/g
```

If someone doesn't mind helping me out here and also explain to me what each part of their regex is doing, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: sorry, but `[1|3|5|7|9]` also matches `|`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with `/(?<=[13579]{1})[05]|^[05]$/`.

This utilises two conditionals. One that checks for the presence of an odd character in the second-to-last position when there's at least two characters in the string, and one that checks for a single character string.

Breaking this down:

- `(?<=[13579]{1})` - does a **[positive lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)** on exactly one odd character
- `[05]` - match a `0` or a `5` directly following the lookbehind
- `|` - denotes an `OR`
- `^` denotes the start of the string
- `[05]` - match a `0` or a `5`
- `$` - the end of the string

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var re = /(?<=[13579]{1})[05]|^[05]$/;
console.log(re.test('12345')); // 12345 should return `false`
console.log(re.test('12335')); // 12335 should return `true`
console.log(re.test('1')); // 1 should return `false`
console.log(re.test('5')); // 5 should return `true`
```

And also seen on **[Regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/0u5nde/1)**.

Comment: Your first example is a false positive: `console.log(re.test('12345'));` returns true.

Comment: @MátéSafranka - Fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about it the wrong way.

Try this:

`/([13579])([05])$/g`

Comment: there's no need of using capturing groups here... no need for parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if a the last character in a string is either a "0" or a "5" and also want to check if the second to last character (if it exists) is odd, I think you do not need the capturing groups.

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for your requirements.

[`(?:\D[05]|[13579][05]|^[05])$`](https://regex101.com/r/IWa8xD/1/)

That would match:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\D[05]` Match not a digit and 0 or 5
  - `|` Or
  - `[13579][05]` Match an odd digit and 0 or 5
  - `|` Or
  - `^[05]` Match from the beginning of the string 0 or 5
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` Assert the end of the line

```js
const strings = [
  "00",
  "11",
  "text1",
  "text10",
  "text00",
  "text5",
  "10",
  "05",
  "15",
  "99",
  "12345",
  "12335",
  "0000",
  "0010",
  "5",
  "1",
  "0",
];
let pattern = /(?:[13579][05]|\D[05]|^[05])$/;
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + pattern.test(s));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/(^|[13579])[05]$/
```

Explained:

`[05]$` means "0 or 5 followed by end of string"

`(^|[13579])` means "beginning of string OR 1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9"

Tested in console:

```
re.test('aaa0') - false
re.test('aa15') - true
re.test('aa20') - false
re.test('0') - true
```

Is this what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

As you said

> I want to check to see if a the last character in a string is either a "0" or a "5", but I also want to check to is if the second to last character (if it exists) is odd

Try this :

```js
var rgx = /^([1-9]+[13579][05]|[1-9][05])$/;

function test(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var res = str[i].match(rgx);
    if (res) {
      console.log("match");
    } else {
      console.log("not match");
    }
  }
}

var arr = ["12335", "12350", "45", "10", "12337", "11", "01", "820"];

test(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You would want to do:

```
/(^|[1|3|5|7|9])([0|5])$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/nMX7L2/4

> 1st Capturing Group (^|[1|3|5|7|9])
>
> 1st Alternative ^
>
> ^ asserts position at start of the string
>
> 2nd Alternative [|1|3|5|7|9]
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [|1|3|5|7|9]
>   |1|3|5|7|9 matches a single character in the list |13579 (case sensitive)
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [1|3|5|7|9]
>
> 1|3|5|7|9 matches a single character in the list 1|3|5|7|9 (case sensitive)
>
> 2nd Capturing Group ([0|5])
>
> Match a single character present in the list below [0|5]
>
> 0|5 matches a single character in the list 0|5 (case sensitive)
>
> $ asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)

Comment: from your example, `[0|5]` matches also `|`, so the whole regexp will match something ending in `||`, `3|`, and `|0`, for example.  It also matches a string with one digit (nobody told you to add an exception, the string must be at least two digits, It must have a second to last char, and it has to be in the set `[13579]`. Test your own regexp before posting an answer.